# How to format excel report in Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv, report, xls

I use the following method to generate excel report, but I also need to format some cells like:

1. Bold headers
2. Indent for all cells
3. Align right for a column (price values)

How can I apply these formats to the following approach?

```
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/form-data";
private static final String FILE_NAME = "DemoReport";
private static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".xlsx";

public MultipartFile export(final UUID uuid) throws IOException {
    final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");
    int rowCount = 0;

    writeTitles(sheet.createRow(rowCount++), titles); // private method

    // code omitted

    final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(FILE_NAME, FILE_EXTENSION);

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LoggingUtils.error("error... ", e);
    }

    final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

    final String fileName = FILE_NAME.concat(FILE_EXTENSION);
    return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
            fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
}
```

Comment: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-format-cell-style-in-excel-document/ might help

Comment: I think you should manage header cell format in the method `writeTitles`, which is not shown here. Making them bold would require you to (1) create a `Font` in the workbook, (2) set it to bold and then apply that `Font` to the `CellStyle` you use before you apply the style at the cell. Alignments (vertical and horizontal) must be applied at cellstyle level. That means: Create a `CellStyle` for headers and column cells. Then simply apply it at every cell you write to and want it to be formatted (styled).

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Thanks a lot, but it generated empty file. So, is it possible to use `XSSF...` instead of `HSSF...` for each place in your example?

Comment: @deHaar Thanks a lot for your valuable helps. But, could you please post your suggestion as a code instead of commenting like a letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *indent for all cells*, but here's some snippet that creates a `CellStyle` for a header row. That means it defines background and foreground colors, centers the cell content vertically and horizontally and applies a bold font:

```
// create a CellStyle for your header cells
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
/* 
 * set background fill of the cell
 * (yes, this is called "setFillForegroundColor", why so ever...)
 */
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
// create a font and set its weight to bold for the header row
Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
// then apply the font to the cell style
cellStyle.setFont(font);
// arrange content alignment for the cell
cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
// apply the configured cell style
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Afterwards, use this cell style for each header cell.

Your code example does not really provide a place for this, so I guess it would be best placed in your `writeTitles` method.

Take this as an example for cell styles in general, you could set `VerticalAlignment.RIGHT` for every cell in the column containing price values.

You can apply desired borders via `CellStyle`s as well... Just take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mean that, when opening generated excel file the column sizes is smaller than the length of cell texts. So, I need to set the cell widths automatically (or a fixed size by giving width value). **PLUS**, I also need some left padding for each cell. How can I do this?

Comment: @Henry You can `autoSizeColumn(int column)` in a `Sheet` in order to adjust the cell width to the width of its content. Indentation in a cell is an issue, I don't know a solution for it at the moment.

Comment: I tried `sheet.autoSizeColumn(2)` before your comment, but there seems to be no change related to the width of any columns.

Comment: When / where in your code have you tried it? If it works or not heavily depends on if you apply it after the entire column was filled or somewhere before. In my experience, it is best placed short before writing the workbook to a file.